# Delete FileField from file system and record in database

Tags: django

My codes:

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        if self.exists(name):
            print "Alreay exists:" + str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
            try:
                os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
            except Exception as e:
                print "Exception when delete "+str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))+","+str(e)
        return name

class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="psfiles", max_length=500, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.file.name
        super(MyFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(MyFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to delete the file from file system and database. But the above codes cannot delete the record in the database. What is a good solution to overwrite the existing file when new file (with same name) uploaded.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

A bad idea is to query the files by slug="psfiles/"+key and delete them before uploading the file with the same name, just like:

```
def post(self, request):
    try:
        psfiles = []
        for key, value in request.FILES.dict().iteritems():   
            MyFile.objects.filter(slug="psfiles/"+key).delete()
            psfile = MyFile.objects.create(file=value)
```

But the "psfiles/" is wired. In the model, self.slug = self.file.name. why there is "psfiles/" before each slug?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Now, I used the following codes to do query and delete, also a signal (recommended by @rafalmp) was sent to delete the file in the file system:

```
old_files = MyFile.objects.filter(file='psfiles/'+value.name)
    if old_files:
    error.append( 'File with same name (' + value.name + ') already exists. Replace it.' )
    old_files.delete()
```

**Any better ways?** How to replace the hardcode "psfiles/"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pre_delete` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/) to remove file when the database record gets deleted:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="psfiles", max_length=500, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    (...)

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyFile)
def remove_file(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    instance.file.delete(save=False)
```

Comment: In fact, I want to delete database record automatically after file deleted. and I prefer to delete them together.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to automate deletion of a database record when the corresponding file is deleted from system; as for your question - why there is "psfiles/" before each slug - models.FileField.name stores full path relative to MEDIA_URL, so the "upload_to" parameter (and a forward slash) is prepended to the file name.